# Call to a member function users() on null in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to add data but i got error Call to a member function users() on null it was working fine i dont know what wrong in my code i did not even changed my code.

I know its error when user is not logged in but my user is also logged in i am testing api using postman.

Here my controller code:

```
                   DB::beginTransaction();

    try{

        $request->request->add(['created_by' => Auth::user()->id]);
        $group = Group::where('name', $request->get('name'))->first();
        $group->users()->attach($request->get('group_members', [])); // error on this line users()

        DB::commit();

        return response([
            'status' => true,
            'message' => 'Group added',
        ], 200);

    } catch(\Exception $ex) {
        DB::rollback();
        return response([
            'status' => false,
            'message' => __('messages.validation_errors'),
            'errors' => $ex->getMessage(),
        ], 500);
    }
```

My routes:

```
  Route::middleware('jwt.auth')->group(function() {

Route::post('add_group', "GroupController@addGroup");

 });
```

My Group Model:

```
                  public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Users\User', 'group_members');
}
```

My user model:

```
             public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group', 'group_members');
}
```

My postman body request:

```
       {
"name": "Steve",
"group_members": [4,6]
       }
```

as i said nothing is changed in code it was working fine a day ago.

Your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The requested group probably couldn't be found. What does `dd($group)` output?

Comment: i dd($group) but still the same error

Comment: You'll have to call this before this line: `$group->users()->attach(...)`

Comment: Hey @Dan its actually your help that we discussed yesterday and i solved my problem now here is again this issue

Comment: it showing null

Comment: Then the group couldn't be found in the first place. Does a group with the name you've requested exist in the database?

Comment: No it does not exit but did i need to create separate api to create the group? and then assign group members against this api?

Comment: can i do this using this api same time create group and same time assign group memebers?

Comment: Can you tell me the better solution should i create a separate api to create a group name?

Comment: Usually, you'll have different methods to create and update an entry. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: Have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#other-creation-methods You can use FindorNew. This way if it can't find a group, it will create a new one with whatever parameters you pass.

Comment: are u there?....

Comment: @syed1234 check you api driver at `config/app.php`, set it to jwt and then you can get user through `$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()`

Comment: hey @Dan are u there?

Answer (score 0):

You are using JWT-Auth, so you need to set your Api driver to 'jwt' in app/config.php
then you can access the current user using

```
$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()
```

Don't forget to pass token as authorization header in your requests.